# Revit addin: CefSharp.Wpf file not found

Tags: .net, wpf, cefsharp, revit-api

I want to implement a Browser addin for Revit, therefore I use CefSharp. So it should be a dockable window with a WPF Browser in it. I installed `CefSharp Version 85.3.130` and using `.Net Framework 4.7.2`.

Everything looks fine in Visual Studio and the build works fine too, but when I start Revit I get a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`. Please help :)

Comment: Historically revit used CefSharp internally and limited the version you could use as detailed in https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/revit-2019-1-add-in-and-cefsharp-library/td-p/8205740 I don't know much about revit myself having never used it. You might want to try their support forum for clues if you are using a newer version of revit. Potentially you can run the browser out of process and use a newer version,  a quick search yields https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/04/set-floor-level-and-use-ipc-for-disentanglement.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Revit 2020 automatically initializes CEFsharp](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/04/whats-new-in-the-revit-2020-api.html#4.1.1) and requires CEFsharp version 65.0.1.